# Two SSD, one with Windows, one with Ubuntu. How to choose boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

Got a computer with Win10 on SSD#1. I installed Kubuntu 18.04 on a new SSD#2, following the steps of [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/1033746/672526). But now, it boots directly on the Kubuntu SSD#2.

For information, I can't boot on Win10 SSD#1 in *UEFI mode* (never could). Boot settings are in *UEFI+Legacy mode*.

Any advice to get a menu to choose on which SSD to boot?

Comment: What brand/model system? May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please attach link to the summary report, the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair
  Have you updated UEFI for your model system? Many need that. But note that the UEFI settings you changed, you probably have to redo as new UEFI uses defaults.

Comment: I suggest you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test , https://en.I suggest you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI . One will have the Answer. Read the others to understand that one.