# Install Ubuntu 18.04 on HDD, while Windows on SSD (Laptop)

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, system-installation, windows-10

I have a laptop with 512gb SSD with 1TB HDD. Windows 10 is installed on the SSD. I want to install Ubuntu 18.04 on the HDD. So the Windows will occupy the SSD, and the Ubuntu on HDD. Will it work if I ran the normal installation of Ubuntu, assuming I'll choose the whole HDD partition? How can I achieve this?

Comment: If you have a 512GB SSD, I would make a 25GB / (root) partition on SSD so Ubuntu is fast. But have /home and/or all data on HDD.You may want both /home and a NTFS data partition to share some data. You need to be sure to boot Ubuntu installer in same boot mode as Windows, probably UEFI, not BIOS so Ubuntu installs in UEFI boot mode. Default install will just put all of / in one large partition on HDD.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI & https://askubuntu.com/questions/913716/dual-boot-on-seperate-drives-best-configuration

Comment: Thanls @oldfred, but I rather want to completely separate the OSes by drives. I'm not concerned at Ubuntu to boot fast, so can I install it on the HDD?

Comment: @oldfred I found an answer here (https://askubuntu.com/a/1126970/976993). The OP's question involved two SSDs on a desktop. I assume this works too in laptop with SSD + HDD right?

Comment: Yes, it does apply to SSD/HDD as well as SSD/SSD.

Comment: New systems now have a way to logically turn off a drive. Easier than unplugging the Windows drive. Ubuntu's ubiquity installer will only install grub to first drive, sda or first NVMe drive. It shares it ok with Windows, but then part of system will be on HDD and boot is on first drive. I prefer to partition in advance, but not required. But also like separating system / (root) from data or separate /home or data partition(s). UEFI/gpt partitioning in Advance, new versions do not need swap partition:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu