# ISSUE: Dual Boot Windows 10 and Linux Ubuntu on Separate SSD

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

This question is in regards to an existing thread: [Dual Boot Windows 10 and Linux Ubuntu on Separate SSD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033497/dual-boot-windows-10-and-linux-ubuntu-on-separate-ssd/1126970#1126970).

I am facing an issue with regards to Part-IV / Figure 8 from the thread above.

After assigning letter G to the volume, I tried executing `cd /d g:`. However, I get an error `"Access is denied"`. I am unsure how to fix it, and proceed with rest of the steps mentioned in the thread above.

Appreciate any help/advice.

Comment: Please edit into your post the output of your terminal when you try to run your command `cd /d g:`

Comment: That link is probably a Microsoft version of something.  The syntax is different ( "/" on options instead of "-", and the options used on rmdir and cd are nonexistent for Ubuntu/bash.  Look for another tutorial, it's not really as complicated as that one makes it.

Comment: Yes he has to run that command at the Windows command prompt with admin rights. There are better methods to install Ubuntu alongside Win 10 dual boot.

Comment: @Raffles: That's right, thanks anyway. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments!

I found an alternate way to install and use Ubuntu, and it worked okay.

[Link](https://www.58bits.com/blog/2020/02/28/how-create-truly-portable-ubuntu-installation-external-usb-hdd-or-ssd).