# Windows crashes booting from Grub, but not BIOS

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows, windows-10

This is an uber unique problem I haven't found online. I installed Ubuntu on a 125 GB partition on my HDD, so that I could dual boot alongside Windows 10, which is installed on my SSD. It works, as in, I see the grub menu open when I boot up my computer, and Ubuntu works perfectly fine.

However! When I select Windows 10 from the Grub boot list, it says Recovery, and tells me that winload.efi had errors or didn't exist. But if I boot up, change the BIOS to put my SSD before Ubuntu, then Windows loads -- that's where I'm typing this from.

I'm really unsure of what to do -- this is all new to me, and I found a few other questions here that sort of matched my problem, but they either had complex solutions or the OP just said they fixed it.

I've tried startup repair, I've tried googling this a bunch, I'm kinda at my wits end. Any ideas?

Comment: Grub only boots working Windows. And that includes not having hibernation flag on, which fast start up sets. And Windows turns fast start up back on with updates. So make sure fast start up is off. If UEFI install, which you should only use with Windows 10, you can boot Windows directly from UEFI boot menu. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: Your problem is you are trying to dual boot on 2 different drives which is a bit tricky! I found this post that might help your with your issue:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033497/dual-boot-windows-10-and-linux-ubuntu-on-separate-ssd There is always the simpler solution of installing both operating systems on the first ssd, I'm sure that will work just fine as well :)
good luck!

Comment: I managed to get it working. Looks like I had some missing boot files in my SSD (probably because I transferred data a while ago.) Working now. Thanks!