# How to install ubuntu in second ssd hard disk and dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 20.04, ssd

I have two SSD hard disks on my computer first is 240GB(gigabyte) and the second is 512GB(hp), my windows is already installed in my first SSD 240GB(gigabyte), now I want to use ubuntu and I want to install ubuntu in my second SSD 512GB(hp), and my question is, is this possible to dual boot where I choose to with ubuntu or windows when pc in is turn on,

I tried with [This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033497/dual-boot-windows-10-and-linux-ubuntu-on-separate-ssd) and install Ubuntu alongside the windows option on the second SSD but after install when ubuntu need `Restart` I clicked `Restart Now` but I can't find choose where I go with Ubuntu or Windows, how can I do that with the perfect way if you anyone has done this before then please guide me to the right way.

`TIA`

Comment: If you intend to have both drives connected all the time it is straightforward. Boot from a USB pendrive, run the installer and select the second drive for Ubuntu. There will be some bootloader files installed into the EFI system partition in the first drive, but the Windows partition C: will be untouched if you manage to select the second drive for Ubuntu. So double-check that you select the correct drive before you let the installer go ahead.

Comment: Dual Boot advice:

I suggest you read `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test` , `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS` , `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record` , `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table` , `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI` . One will have the Answer. Read the others to understand that one.

Comment: Be aware of launchpad bug 1396379 for UEFI installs.  The location of the bootloader you specify is ignored, and the bootloaders probably get put on the first EFI on disk sda.

Comment: Did you partition in advance & include an ESP on second drive. Ubuntu installer will not install grub boot loader to Ubuntu ESP by default. Several work arounds in bug report. http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu Be sure to use gpt partitioning & boot installer in UEFI boot mode. Remove esp flag from Windows before install to second or external drive - Tim Richardson
https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator/1056079#1056079 (Also in Bug report).